# CanvasCamera Plugin

Tags: phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to implement the CanvasCamera Plugin, I followed the procedure but when I try to run the project in the simulator I mark 8 errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress", referenced from:
      -[CanvasCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in CanvasCamera.o
  "_CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow", referenced from:
      -[CanvasCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in CanvasCamera.o
  "_CVPixelBufferGetHeight", referenced from:
      -[CanvasCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in CanvasCamera.o
  "_CVPixelBufferGetWidth", referenced from:
      -[CanvasCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in CanvasCamera.o
  "_CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress", referenced from:
      -[CanvasCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in CanvasCamera.o
  "_CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress", referenced from:
      -[CanvasCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in CanvasCamera.o
  "_kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey", referenced from:
      -[CanvasCamera startCapture:withDict:] in CanvasCamera.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could you help me with this?

I'm testing in
Mac mini intel i5 processor
Os X 10.8.2
Xcode 4.5

Answer (score 1):

You forgot adding the CoreVideo.framework library in the Build Phases tab of the project.

And when you press Product/Archive, you will get the bug. Check [Building an archive for XCode 4.6 release with phonegap v 2.9 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351446/building-an-archive-for-xcode-4-6-release-with-phonegap-v-2-9-fails) to resolve.