# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have developed an iOS Application with Xcode 5, release 6.
I have successfully run the application on the iOS simulator and on my iPhone 5 (iOS7 beta6)

I'm following Apple's tutorial on how to release the app onto the app store (bit complicated).

I've gotten to the point where they want me to "Archive" my project. Everytime I attempt to archive it, it gives me this error:

> ld: file not found:
>   /Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mobile-cwvgezbobyhhzzccadgoqizqcmfd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/trial/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/libCordova.a
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Comment: The problem is that libCordoba.a is missing.
Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351446/building-an-archive-for-xcode-4-6-release-with-phonegap-v-2-9-fails/17372031#17372031

Comment: @Enrique: I think the question you link to is for an older version

Answer (score 4):

Well, since you are using Xcode 5, Apple says on the member center:

> "Xcode 5 Developer Preview cannot be used to submit apps to the iOS or
>   Mac App Store. Continue to use the publicly released version of Xcode
>   to compile and submit apps to the App Stores."

But I will show some suggestions anyway:

- With Xcode, click on your project's icon on the left, select the tab *Build Phases > Compile Sources* and click on the "*+*" to check if there is some file `.m` to be imported.
- Check if you imported all the frameworks you are using to your project.
- Go to *Build Settings* and look for *Architectures* and set `armv7` instead of `armv6` and `armv7s`.

I hope this helps.